# Can we build app with partial cordova and native development?

Tags: android, .net, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I just want to know that can we make an app e.g. android app. in partial cordova and partial in native. Will it be a single build in the end or not? I am a newbie in this and after alot of search unable to figure it out. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Yes, you can do that using [CordovaWebView](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/next/index.html#2-performance-considerations).
have a look at the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Start by reading the [docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/webviews/index.html). Also take a look at this [example](http://devgirl.org/2014/07/22/mixing-cordova-phonegap-components-with-nativ/). It's a bit old, but the concept is basically the same.